# I would like to make a colormap from a matrix, with making difference, which way we have got the negative values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colormap, imshow

We have two terms, two parameters (*h*, *h0*) and a variable *T*. We can define a certain value of *T*, where the difference of the two terms divided by L is equal to zero.

With this *T* value, we can calculate *g0*, *gc* and *gs* operators, and then *witness1* and *witness2*.

Then we make this whole calculation with running parameters (from 0.03 to 3): `h0=0.03, h=0.03`; *h0=0.06, h=0.03*; ...; `h0=3, h=0.03`; `h0=0.03, h=0.06`; ...; h0=3, h=3

Then we select the witness with the lower value, and put it to the proper place in the matrix.

The values can be both positive and negative. We are interested in where will be the result negative, and from which witness we got the result. I have plotted the results from the matrix, the negative values with yellow, and the positive with white. Now I would like to plot the negative numbers from witness1 with blue, and the negative numbers from witness2 with yellow. Then I would like to norm the graph from 0-100 to 0-3.

How can I make this?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors


def g0operator(T, gamma, h, L):
    k = -math.pi
    d=2*math.pi/L
    g0=0
    while k <= math.pi:
        g0 = g0 + (((math.tanh(math.sqrt(((gamma * math.sin(k)) ** 2) + (h - math.cos(k)) ** 2) / T))) * (
                    1 / (math.sqrt(
                ((gamma * math.sin(k)) ** 2) + (h - math.cos(k)) ** 2))) * ((h - math.cos(k))))
        k = k + d
    g0 = g0 / L
    return g0

def gsoperator(T, gamma, h, L):
    gs=0
    k = -math.pi
    d=2*math.pi/L
    while k <= math.pi:
        gs = gs + ((math.tanh(math.sqrt(((gamma * math.sin(k)) ** 2) + (h - math.cos(k)) ** 2) / T)) * (1 /
             (math.sqrt(((gamma * math.sin(k)) ** 2) + (h - math.cos(k)) ** 2))) * (
             ((math.sin(k)) ** 2)))
        k = k + d
    gs = -(gs / L) * gamma
    return gs

def gcoperator(T, gamma, h, L):
    d=2*math.pi/L
    gc=0
    k = -math.pi
    while k <= math.pi:
        gc = gc + ((math.tanh(np.sqrt(((gamma * np.sin(k)) ** 2) + (h - np.cos(k)) ** 2) / T)) * (1 /
                  np.sqrt(((gamma * np.sin(k)) ** 2) + (h - np.cos(k)) ** 2))) * (np.cos(k) * ((np.cos(k) - h)))
        k = k + d
    gc = gc / L
    return gc

def first_term(gamma, h, T, L):
    c=-math.pi
    d=2*math.pi/L
    first=0
    while c <= math.pi:
        first = first + (math.tanh(math.sqrt(((gamma * math.sin(c)) ** 2) + (h - math.cos(c)) ** 2) / T) * math.sqrt(
            ((gamma * math.sin(c))
            ** 2) + (h - math.cos(c)) ** 2))
        c=c+d
    return first

def second_term(h, h0, gamma, L):
    second=0
    c=-math.pi
    d=2*math.pi/L
    while c<=math.pi:
        second = second + abs(((math.cos(c) - h0) * (math.cos(c) - h) + ((gamma * math.sin(c)) ** 2)) / (
            math.sqrt(((gamma * math.sin(c)) ** 2) + (h0 - math.cos(c)) ** 2)))
        c = c + d
    return second

def witness1(gs, g0, gc):
    W = (-1 / 4) * (2 * abs(gs) + ((g0) ** 2) - ((gc) ** 2) + ((gs) ** 2) - 1)
    return W

def witness2(gs, g0, gc):
    w=-(1/4)*(-(g0**2)+(gc**2)-(gs**2)-1+2*math.sqrt((g0**2)+(gc**2)))
    return w


h=0.03
h0=0.03
T=2.5
gamma=0.6
K=2.5
L=100000
matrix=np.zeros((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for b in range(100):
        K = 2.5
        T = 2.5
        result=1
        while abs(result) > 10 ** (-12):
            c = -math.pi
            first = first_term(gamma, h, T, L)
            second = second_term(h, h0, gamma, L)
            result = (first - second) / L
            if result > 0:
                T = T + K / 2
            elif result < 0:
                T = T - K / 2
            K = K / 2
        gc = gcoperator(T, gamma, h, L)
        gs = gsoperator(T, gamma, h, L)
        g0 = g0operator(T, gamma, h, L)
        W = witness1(gs, g0, gc)
        w = witness2(gs, g0, gc)
        if W < w:
            matrix[i, b] = W
        else:
            matrix[i, b] = w
        h0=h0+0.03
    h=h+0.03
    h0=0.03
np.savetxt('matrixgamma=0.6.txt', matrix)
a=np.loadtxt('matrixgamma=0.6.txt')
cmap=colors.ListedColormap(['yellow', 'white'])
bounds=[-2, 0, 2]
norm=colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

img=plt.imshow(a, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(img, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Because I'm not sure the answer I posted below is exactly on topic, I'd appreciate very much your feedback. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm sorry but I have simplified a little bit your `witnessN` functions, but I hope that you can adapt my solution, in which the key points are

- to save the values for the grid evaluations of `witnessN`
- to use Numpy's logical functions
- to use the fact that Booleans can be used as `0` or `1` integers,

With respect to plotting, you can omit the `plt.contourf` statement, but I like the additional lines subdividing the fields.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap

witness1 = lambda X, Y: np.sin(X-Y/2)
witness2 = lambda X, Y: np.cos(X/2+2*Y)

x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 241)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
W = witness1(X, Y)
w = witness2(X, Y)

Wp, wp, Wgtw = W>0, w>0, W>w

values = np.where(Wgtw, W, w)

colors  = np.where(np.logical_and(1-Wgtw, 1-wp), 0, 0)
colors += np.where(np.logical_and(  Wgtw, 1-Wp), 1, 0)
colors += np.where(np.logical_and(  Wgtw,   Wp), 2, 0)
colors += np.where(np.logical_and(1-Wgtw,   wp), 3, 0)

# change colors to your taste
#                      w<0, W<0, W>0, w>0
cm = ListedColormap([  'y', 'b', 'r', 'g'])
norm=BoundaryNorm([-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5], 4)

pc = plt.pcolor(X, Y, colors, norm=norm, cmap=cm)
ct = plt.contour(X, Y, values, [-.9, -0.1, 0.1,  0.9], colors='k')
lb = plt.clabel(ct)
cf = plt.contourf(X, Y, colors, norm=norm, cmap=cm, alpha=0.6)
cb = plt.colorbar(pc)
cb.set_ticks([0, 1, 2, 3])
cb.set_ticklabels(['w<0', 'W<0', 'W>0', 'w>0'])
plt.show()
```